# Issues with Eye Rig

Tags: rigging, bones

I created this rig by myself and everything is centered on the axies but when I rotate his head to either side of him his eyes do not rotate and neither do the eye bones, the targets Rotate with the head but the eye bones don't.

Photos of my issue without rig showing, sorry.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constraint to copy the rotation from the correct bone as shown:

[image]

I did this only for the left eye and as you can see below the left eye rotates correctly with the head while the right eye doesn't:

[image]